# Is there a way to clear a certain part of the console?

Tags: c#, console

I have a part of the console that needs to keep updating with values of different row amounts. I know of Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth)) but that is only for a single row. I have a certain row where the clearing must begin and head downwards to the bottom. The top part must be unchanged. Is there a simple command such as the previous one of would I have to use loops/counters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using Console.Clear() and then rewriting the lines you want to stay the same. You could also use Console.SetCursorPosition and then write over the lines to clear:

```
// Clear method
Console.WriteLine("Line1");
Console.WriteLine("Line2");
Console.WriteLine("Line3 to erase");
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("Line1");
Console.WriteLine("Line2");

// SetCursorPosition method
Console.WriteLine("Line1");
Console.WriteLine("Line2");
Console.WriteLine("Line3 to erase");
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
Console.WriteLine("                           ");
```

The Clear/rewrite method is usually faster and unless you are writing text several times per second you should not see any flashing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the SetCursorPosition method to write where you want
http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.80).aspx